# Ajax requests crashing browser on dashboard page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dashboard page that checks for an updated json response to display on a page. The page and rest of the site, are hosted on the same machine as the browser that displays it. It is intended to be left on, and on that page continuously. It consists of two parts, a javascript/jquery fetcher that calls a PHP page that reads a database returning a "payload" value if the content has changed, or just the last timestamp of the check if not. It works currently pulling the notes, as they change, however it has problems

Ok the problems:

1: In chrome console getting this message everytime the page loads:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

2: I have noticed a huge increase in the amount of RAM used by the browser after adding this to the page. After about 4 hours the browser crashes.

the JS code:

```
var lastcheck;
var content_main = $('#notes');
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
            setInterval(function() {
                updateJson();
            }, 5000);  
});

function updateJson() {
  var request = '/sections/noteboard/notes.php?new=1&timestamp='+ (lastcheck ? lastcheck : 0);

  $.ajax({
    url: request,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.payload) {        // new data
        lastcheck = result.time;   // update stored timestamp
        content_main.html(result.payload); // update html element
      } else {                     // no new data, update only timestamp
        lastcheck = result.time;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The PHP code:

```
$timestamp = 0;
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['timestamp'])) {
    $timestamp = $_GET['timestamp'];
}
if ($timestamp) {
 $where = ' WHERE timing >= '.$timestamp;
}
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `mirror_notes` ". $where ." ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
$output = array();
$myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($row_cnt=='1' && $myrow['message'] !== '') {   // do we have any script output ?
    $output['payload'] = stripslashes($myrow['message']);  // your current script output would go in this variable
}
$output['time'] = time();      // so we know when did we last check for payload update
$json = json_encode($output, ((int)JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); // jsonify the array
echo $json;                    // send it to the client 
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
exit();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am an beginner with jquery, and only modestly better with php.
Thanks

Comment: I would strongly recommend using prepared statements for your queries. ALWAYS is a terrible idea concatenate browser input into your queries without cleaning it. Search for "sql injection".

Comment: True, I would be more concerned about SQL Injection if this page was available outside of our local network. It is a dashboard page that is hosted on the same computer that runs the browser for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone would leave the browser open for so long to crash.

A simple solution would be to use sockets. It's not so hard to open a socket with php and start a communication with the browser. You should look into that.

Comment: Well the page is a dashboard, so it is intended to be left open indefinaitely

Comment: if you think so, then you should definitely look into sockets.

Comment: I don't understand how sockets would be better than ajax for clientside updates of a browser page...?

Comment: you can make it like when there is an update the client will be notified, no need to load so many requests. Thats the point.